# R: ordering facets by value rather than alphabetical order in a ggplot2 plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

A couple of weeks ago I used ggplot2 to create a faceted plot where the facets were ordered by the last value in the data frame. I had no major problems until it came to reordering, as I haven't really assimilated all the complications of orders, factors and levels. Still, after an hour or two (or three) of referring to SO posts I got it working.

When I came back to the script today it was no longer "working" in that it is now sorting the facets by alphabetical order rather than by the final value of the data frame. (I think that I originally "fixed" the problem while messing around at the R console and did not actually add the solution to the script.) Rather than spending another couple of hours on this tonight I'm going to throw myself on the mercy of SO.

Q. How can I sort the facets by a specified value rather than by the alphabetical order of the names of each facet? Please note the following code is an example only; the real data has several dozen items.

Edited code below to reflect additional input from @joran; the facets are now sorted and filled appropriately. Mission successful.

```
# Version 3
require(ggplot2) ## NB This script assumes you have ggplot2 v0.90
require(scales)
require(plyr)
require(lubridate)
require(reshape)

set.seed(12345)
monthsback <- 15
date <- as.Date(paste(year(now()),month(now()),"1",sep="-")) - months(monthsback)
myitems <- data.frame(mydate=seq(as.Date(date), by="month", length.out=monthsback),
                      aaa = runif(monthsback, min = 600, max = 800),
                      bbb = runif(monthsback, min = 100, max = 200),
                      ccc = runif(monthsback, min = 1400, max = 2000),
                      ddd = runif(monthsback, min = 50, max = 120))

myitems <- melt(myitems, id = c('mydate'))

change_from_start <- function(x) {
   (x - x[1]) / x[1]
}

myitems <- ddply(myitems, .(variable), transform, value = change_from_start(value))
myitems$mydate <- as.Date(myitems$mydate, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
myvals <- myitems[myitems$mydate == myitems$mydate[nrow(myitems)],] # get values on which to sort facets
myvals <- within(myvals, variable <- factor(variable, as.character(myvals[order(myvals$value, decreasing = T),]$variable),ordered = TRUE))
myitems <- within(myitems, variable <- factor(variable, as.character(myvals[order(myvals$value, decreasing = T),]$variable),ordered = TRUE))
print(levels(myitems$variable)) # check to see if ordering succeeded
myitems$fill <- ifelse(myitems$variable == "ddd", "blue", "darkgreen")

    p <- ggplot(myitems, aes(y = value, x = mydate, group = variable)) +
      geom_rect(aes(xmin = as.Date(myitems$mydate[1]), xmax = Inf, fill = fill), ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf) +
      scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "darkgreen")) +
      geom_line(colour = "black") +
      geom_text(data = myvals, aes(x = as.Date(myitems$mydate[1]) + 250, y = 0.2, label = sprintf("%1.1f%%", value * 100))) +
      facet_wrap( ~ variable, ncol = 2) +
      geom_hline(yintercept = 0, size = 0.6, linetype = "dotdash") +
      scale_y_continuous(label = percent_format()) +
      scale_x_date(expand = c(0,0), labels = date_format("%Y-%m"), breaks = date_breaks("year")) +
      xlab(NULL) +
      ylab(NULL) +
      opts(legend.position = "none") +
      opts(panel.grid.minor = theme_blank()) +
      opts()

print(p)
```

[image: Image showing that facets are now sorted properly but that the fill is no longer working]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. The line that converts `myitems$variable` to a factor should specify `ordered = TRUE`, to assure that it will be an ordered factor.
2. Your `geom_text` call uses a *separate data frame* whose corresponding variable isn't a factor (or ordered) so it's stomping on the ordered nature of the one in `myitems`.

Convert them *both* or ordered factors, and you should be fine.

Comment: I added `ordered = TRUE` to the myvals data frame and the myitems data frame and now they both sort as one would expect. However... Now I am finding that the fill is broken, presumably because it is filling on the fill column and not the sorted factor levels. That is, if "ddd" is in the second facet the second facet should be coloured blue and the rest green, but it is always the fourth facet - the original location of "ddd" - that is filled blue. I have experimented with trying to order the fill column to resolve this but cannot get it to work. Should this be a separate question?

Comment: @SlowLearner Change `fill = myitems$fill` to `fill = fill`. It's a subtle difference, but otherwise your fill variable isn't tied to the other variables in the data frame, since you've just passed it a free standing vector.

Comment: Argghhh so that was it. Subtle is the right word... Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Facet are ordered in the same order as variables in source data.frame. 
Thus as a basic hack you can just order variables name when creating the data.frame :

```
myitems <- data.frame(mydate=seq(as.Date(date), by="month", length.out=monthsback),
        'ccc' = runif(monthsback, min = 1400, max = 2000),
        'aaa' = runif(monthsback, min = 600, max = 800),
        'ddd' = runif(monthsback, min = 50, max = 120),
        'bbb' = runif(monthsback, min = 100, max = 200)
        )
```

If you need to reorder at the end of the process, then arrange() might be the best solution.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I did not make it clear in my question, but the real data has several dozen items and the values by which the facets should be ordered will change frequently, so manual re-ordering would be rather burdensome.